# Find a differential equation for which a series is a solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is just a general question. Given a power series in one real variable, is it always possible to find a differential equation for which the series is a solution? If not, when is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean a power series in one variable?

Comment: @jowehler Yes, thank you. I have updated the requirement in the main post.

Comment: The power series should converge in some interval, so that it defines some function $f$. Then $f$ is analytic, hence differentiable, so it satisfies the equation $f' = g$ where $g$ is defined to be $f'$... Is this acceptable? If not, what kind of differential equation do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a power series in one real variable $x \in \mathbb R$ converges for $x-x_0 < r, x_0 \in \mathbb R $ fixed, then it extends to a power series in one complex variable $z \in \mathbb C$ which converges for $|z-x_0| < r$. Hence the "natural" domain of definition of power series are complex variables.

Considered from a certain point of view, complex analysis is the theory of convergent power series of one complex variable. Because a function $f$ is *holomorphic* in an open subset $U \subset \mathbb C$ iff it can be represented around each point of $U$ by a convergent power series.

Consider a function $f:U \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ with $U \subset \mathbb C$ open. After decomposing complex numbers $z = x + i y \in U$ into real part $x$ and imaginary part $y$ and analogously decomposing $g(x,y) := f(x+iy)$ as

$$g(x,y) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$$

with two real-valued functions $u$ and $v$, we have the **Cauchy-Riemann** differential equations: $f$ is holomorphic iff the pair $(u,v)$ satisfies the two partial differential equations

$$u_x = v_y, u_y = -v_x.$$

Summing up: There is a strong relation between convergent power series and differential equations. But the link is not a single ordinary differential equation. Instead it is a system of two partial differential equations. They relate the real part and the imaginary part.